Is it possible that any product of transpositions can be grouped to form the unique product of disjoint, non-identity cycles of a permutation?
It is clear how to form a product of transpositions from the unique product of disjoint and non-identity cycles of a permutation. But is it true that for any product of transpositions we can form a product of disjoint, non-identity cycles by just grouping the transpositions?
Stating it in a formal way, consider some $\sigma \in S_m$ being expressed as some product of transpositions as follows
$$\sigma = \prod_{i=1}^n (a_i, b_i) = \prod_{i=1}^k \gamma_i,$$
where all $(a_i, b_i)$ are not necessarily distinct; k, n are the number of disjoint, non-identity cycles and the number of transpositions respectively.
it then follows that exists some specific grouping of transpositions $A_i$ such that for all $1 \leq i \leq k$:
$$A_i \subseteq [1...n] \land \gamma_i = \prod_{j \in A_i} (a_j, b_j),$$
where all $A_i$ are disjoint ordered set, their union is $[1...n]$.
We take each element in $A_i$ in the order they appear to form $\prod_{j \in A_i} (a_j, b_j)$. So, $A_i = \{1, 3, 5, 7\}$ forms the product $(a_1, b_1)(a_3, b_3)(a_5, b_5)(a_7, b_7)$ but $A_i = \{3, 1, 5, 7\}$ forms the product $(a_3, b_3)(a_1, b_1)(a_5, b_5)(a_7, b_7)$, which might be the same as the former.
For example, the permutation $(132)(465) \in S_6$ can be expressed as
$$(132)(465) = (12)(45)(13)(46)$$
So, one partition of $[1...6]$ to get $(132)(465)$ is
$$[(12)(13) = (132)];\quad (45)(46) = (465)$$
Here,
$$\gamma_1 = (132);\quad \gamma_2 = (465)$$
$$(a_1, b_1) = (12);\quad (a_2, b_2) = (45);\quad (a_3, b_3) = (13);\quad (a_4, b_4) = (46)$$
And, our grouping is
$$A_1 = \{1, 3\};\quad A_2 = \{2, 4\}$$
Or second example is,
$$(132)(78)(465) = (12)(78)(12)(45)(12)(46)(13)$$
in $S_8$. The grouping is
$$A_1 = \{1, 3, 5, 7\};\quad A_2 = \{2\};\quad A_3 = \{4, 6\};$$

I'm not sure I understand the question. Please would you elaborate?

Please do not do excessive edits. Edits bump posts to the front page, which is a valuable space.

Disjoint transpositions commute. You are doing some rearranging here that need not be possible every time. One question is whether in any product of transposition $\tau_1\cdots \tau_k$, there is a way of "inserting parentheses" so that $\Bigl(\tau_1\cdots t_{k_1}\Bigr)\Bigl(\tau_{k_1+1}\cdots \tau_{k_2}\Bigr)\cdots\Bigl(\tau_{k_{r}+1}\cdots\tau_{n}\Bigr)$ so each of the parentheses yields a cycle and the resulting cycles are disjoint. But you seem to be also applying a kind of permutation on the transpositions. "Grouping" is imprecise because you do not place order on the indices.

So please clarify. Do you mean, if you have a product of transpositions $\tau_1\cdots\tau_n$ that is equal to a product of $r$ disjoint cycles, can we choose $n_{11}\lt n_{12}\lt\cdots\lt n_{1m_1}$, $n_{21}\lt\cdots\lt n_{2m_2},\ldots, n_{r1}\lt\cdots\lt n_{rm_r}$ so that each index appears exactly once, each product $\tau_{i1}\cdots \tau_{in_i}$ is a cycle, and the resulting $r$ cycles are disjoint?

@ArturoMagidin Order does not matter. Any order of $A_i$ is acceptable to form $\gamma_i$.

You say "order does not matter", and then you edit to say that the order does matter. It looks like you are actually asking what my  second comment states, which means order does matter within each $A_i$, while your comment says "any order of $A_i$ is acceptable". No, apparently it isn't;  the order of $A_i$ is the order in which the original transpositions occurred relative to each other. It is clear that if you have disjoint permutations those commute, so that wasn't an issue.

$(1,3)(1,4)(2,3)(2,4)=(1,4)(2,3)$. How will you group things together?

@DavidA.Craven You're right. It fails :D
